# In how many different ways can 7 friends be seated since Jundullah will always sit on a 3-person seat?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Question overview:**

> A group of 7 people, including Jundullah, will sit in two fixed seats for 3 and 4 people.  In how many different ways can 7 friends be seated since Jundullah will always sit on a 3-person seat?`

**My approach and thoughts:**

*like this in the question* --> □□□ □□□□

*think of seats like this* --> □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □

and Jundullah can only sit in the top 3 seats.

**Q1:** *Is it okay to think like that?*

Jundullah sits on a 3-seater chair in 3 different ways,the remaining 6 people are 6!

result$=3.6! = 2160$.

**Q2:** *My way of going to the conclusion and is the result correct?*

Note:  It's not homework.  It's a personal curiosity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this bot joking?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. This is a common counting problem. You multiply $6!$ by $3$ because Jundullah can sit in $3$ different spots. You multiply by $6!$ because there are $6$ seats remaining for the others to sit in.